# Concatenate Two CSV files or dataframes under a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, concatenation

okay, I can not seem to find the solution so here is my question. I would really appreciate if someone from the stackoverflow community could suggest a solution soon since I have to submit the results.

I have two csv files (can be loaded as dataframes). One csv file has 1458644 rows and 12 columns with all row entries specifying events down to the seconds of multiple days for 6 months duration.

The other csv file with the weather data has 4432 entries , with the weather data of each day specified with the hour (no seconds duration here) of 6 months

What I want to do is combine the entries of both files, using some pythonic operation (or concatenate with the condition), so that the data from the hour entry of second dataframe is added to the first dataframe but the entries for a single hour (specified in 2nd dataframe ) are duplicated and repeated over the single hour of first dataframe

e.g.

First Dataframe

```
Date:                     col1, cl2, 
1/2/2013 12:05:00         yyy   etc. 
1/2/2013 12:12:00         yyy
1/2/2013 13:13:00         yyy
1/2/2013 14:14:00         yyy
1/2/2013 14:30:00         yyy
1/2/2013 14:45:00         yyy
1/2/2013 17:00:00         yyy
1/2/2013 17:17:00         yyy
1/2/2013 17:30:00         yyy
1/2/2013 18:17:00         yyy
1/2/2013 18:30:00         yyy
```

2nd DataFrame

```
Date                      col3  col4
1/2/2013 12:00:00         xxx   overcast  
1/2/2013 13:00:00         xxx   overcast
1/2/2013 14:00:00         xxx   sunny
1/2/2013 15:00:00         xxx   sunny
1/2/2013 16:00:00         xxx   rain
1/2/2013 17:00:00         xxx   rain
1/2/2013 18:00:00         xxx   cloudy
```

The Final result should look like the following:

```
Date:                     col1, col2, col3, col4
1/2/2013 12:05:00         yyy   etc.  xxx   overcast
1/2/2013 12:12:00         yyy         xxx   overcast 
1/2/2013 13:13:00         yyy         xxx   overcast 
1/2/2013 14:14:00         yyy         xxx   sunny
1/2/2013 14:30:00         yyy         xxx   sunny
1/2/2013 14:45:00         yyy         xxx   sunny
1/2/2013 17:00:00         yyy         xxx   rain
1/2/2013 17:17:00         yyy         xxx   rain
1/2/2013 17:30:00         yyy         xxx   rain
1/2/2013 18:17:00         yyy         xxx   cloudy
1/2/2013 18:30:00         yyy         xxx   cloudy
```

Comment: So for each record/row in frame1 you look up the same hour in frame2, and its colunms?  And there are variable numbers of matches between 1 and 2.

Answer (score 3):

If we convert to proper datetimes, this is fairly straightforward:

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

df1['Hour'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1['Date']).floor('h')

combined = df1.merge(df2, left_on='Hour', right_on='Date', how='left',
                     suffixes=('', '_r'))
combined.drop(['Hour', 'Date_r'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Damn, Thanks man, it worked like a charm. Also, there appears to be some rows missing entirely of the RIGHT (df2) dataframe in the combined file. I have checked the 2nd dataframe, there are some columns with missing values but not entirely the row entries of second dataframe are empty.  Any idea, what might be causing this !!

Comment: @Jon_Snow_ glad to be of help. I'm not sure what you mean though - are you saying some of the datetimes aren't converted properly?

Comment: no, i mean the entries of the second dataframe in combined file are missing in some rows completely against the entries of first dataframe. Like df1 has values in that row , but df2 values are not present at all

I guess the datetimes are converted properly, however there are a few cases where the conversion, it seems from 2nd df has failed. One entry, e.g. is missing at 12:00 in datetime of combined file.  I checked in df2, the values for that hour are present.

Comment: @Jon_Snow_ hmm I'm not sure what's happening there. Are your dates month-day-year or day-month-year? That might be causing issues?

Comment: interesting observation man, i will once again look more thoroughly on the file, but the date format seems to be the same in both columns. Thanks MUCH !! They are month-day-year btw